# Replace block with template

Tags: php, forms, magento, layout, block

I need to replace a block with another one.

This is the code that calls the block i need to replace.

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('contact_us_page')->getTitle() ?>
```

I could replace the block calling another block, simply  by replacing `contact_us_page` with the other block's name.

The thing is, i need to change it for a register form there and i guess the best approach would be to load the template `/form/register.phtml` but i don't know how.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I would copy /frontend/base/default/template/form/register.phtml into your theme  /frontend/cooncook/default/template/form/register.phtml and customize it to your heart's content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new static block in backend, eg, `new-static-block.`

Open the static block and put code like this to assign a template to it.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="form/register.phtml"}}
```

Call the static block through code, or in xml (preferred way)